# Запятые при деепричастном обороте

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении после слова сидели:Пленные сидели опустив глаза и боясь пошевелиться.
Нужна ли запятая перед оборотом "в чем дело":Немцы встали, подняв руки и, как видно, еще не понимая в чем дело.
Будут ли однородными определения "нежилая промерзлая землянка". Нужна ли запятая. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пленные сидели опустив глаза и боясь пошевелиться.

Запятая не нужна,т.к. деепричастный оборот тесно связан со сказуемым (сидели с опущенными глазами).

[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
М.: ЧеРо, 1999, §94. Обособленные обстоятельства](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)

Пункт 1, примечание а)

Answer (score 3):

1) Пленные сидели опустив глазА и боясь пошевелИться. **Запятая не нужна**, тесная связь со сказуемым, отсутствует пауза, логическое ударение падает на обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами.

2) Немцы встали, подняв руки и, как видно, еще не понимая,  в чем дело. **Запятая нужна**, это неполное придаточное.

3) Нежилая промерзлая землянка.  **Нет запятой**, определения неоднородные, обозначают разные признаки, сближение признаков вряд ли возможно, перечислительная интонация отсутствует.

Answer (score -1):

> Пленные сидели, опустив глаза и боясь пошевелиться.

Запятая ставится на том основании, что это обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом.

> Немцы встали, подняв руки и, как видно, еще не понимая, в чем дело.

Указанная запятая нужна.

*Нежилая промерзлая* — это неоднородные определения. Определения являются однородными в том случае, если они конкретизируют что-либо по одной категории, например: по цвету, по размеру и т.д. Пример: синие, белые шарики. Что касается пунктуации при неоднородных определениях, то запятая между ними не ставится.

Comment: В первом предложении запятая, действительно, не нужна.

Comment: Согласна с вами.